# PowerBi Rest API GetActivityEvents Properties Missing

Tags: .net, powerbi, azure-functions

my english is not the best, but i'll try anyway.

Im working on a Azure Function .Net Project and [PowerBI Rest Apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin) to get Admin's Data of the endpoint 
[api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents). The problem is that between this endpoint and PowerShell counterpart are properties missing.

PowerShell model

```
 {
"Id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
"RecordType": 20,
"CreationTime": "2020-03-24T23:00:14Z",
"Operation": "ViewReport",
"OrganizationId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
"UserType": 0,
"UserKey": "KKKKKKKKKKKKKKK",
"Workload": "PowerBI",
"UserId": "examples@mail.com",
"ClientIP": "190.196.218.34",
"UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36",
"Activity": "ViewReport",
"ItemName": "Asignaciones",
"WorkSpaceName": "Asignaciones",
"DatasetName": "Asignaciones",
"ReportName": "Asignaciones",
"WorkspaceId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
"AppName": "Asignaciones",
"ObjectId": "Asignaciones",
"DatasetId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
"ReportId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx,
"IsSuccess": true,
"ReportType": "PowerBIReport",
"RequestId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
"ActivityId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
"AppReportId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
"DistributionMethod": "Apps"
```

}

PowerBI RestAPI
Url: Example https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime='2020-03-31T23:00:00.000'&endDateTime='2020-03-31T23:59:59.999'

```
{
        "Id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
        "RecordType": 20,
        "CreationTime": "2020-03-31T00:30:11",
        "Operation": "GenerateCustomVisualAADAccessToken",
        "OrganizationId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
        "UserType": 0,
        "UserKey": "KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK",
        "Workload": "PowerBI",
        "UserId": "example@mail.com",
        "ClientIP": "000.000.000.00",
        "UserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
        "Activity": "GenerateCustomVisualAADAccessToken",
        "IsSuccess": true,
        "RequestId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
        "ActivityId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
        "CustomVisualAccessTokenResourceId": "PowerQuery_PBI_xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx",
        "CustomVisualAccessTokenSiteUri": "https://powerquery.microsoft.com"
    },
```

As you can see, there is a missmatch betweeen properties. The problem is that i need to know what report, dashboard the ActivityEvent is from.

I know that this api has a lot of limitations, and the documentation doesnt help too much.
If you know how can i achieve this in another way, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

So, this endpoint returns a List of objects that can mutate depending on the type of the event that it returns, so "ViewReport" and "ViewDashboards" returns this models

```
{
        "Id": "ca56a114-acae-447d-b815-dc6d82d5d75c",
        "RecordType": 20,
        "CreationTime": "2020-03-31T11:39:25",
        "Operation": "ViewReport",
        "OrganizationId": "49876daa-69a7-40a0-9395-e48ec4021554",
        "UserType": 0,
        "UserKey": "10037FFEACCAF143",
        "Workload": "PowerBI",
        "UserId": "luis.fuentes@arkanosoft.com",
        "ClientIP": "201.215.93.34",
        "UserAgent": "okhttp/4.2.2",
        "Activity": "ViewReport",
        "ItemName": "Colbun_Presentación_v3",
        "WorkSpaceName": "COLBUN_PERU",
        "DatasetName": "Colbun_Presentación_v3",
        "ReportName": "Colbun_Presentación_v3",
        "WorkspaceId": "0bd8f723-27ff-4638-a161-7bc8cda4c5da",
        "ObjectId": "Colbun_Presentación_v3",
        "DatasetId": "db1ffc31-bea6-4aae-9081-581898c8abce",
        "ReportId": "b96353c3-2309-4f18-bbaf-087a60ae97b0",
        "IsSuccess": true,
        "ReportType": "PowerBIReport",
        "RequestId": "7d9ebcef-b4c1-4350-92c6-6af24f66ea87",
        "ActivityId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "DistributionMethod": "Workspace",
        "ConsumptionMethod": "Power BI Mobile"
    },
```

i never saw this because another problems with the Api. Thanks anyways.